# Python-3.x Count the frequency of a specific number from user input

Tags: python-3.x, frequency

I'm trying to make a program that will output **how many times the number 7 appears from a series of numbers (of no particular range) inputted by the user**. **Each number would be a separate input**, not as one.

I have searched far and wide but the solutions I found involved letters, words, or numbers from pre-made lists rather than int from user input and errored when I tried to modify for purpose. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious but I can't figure out how to do this.

(I tried Counter, if num == 100, count(100), for i in range, etc etc - but I'm clearly on the wrong path)

My starting point was trying to modify this one that prints the highest number because I am aiming for a similar format:

```
x = 0
done = False
while not done:
    print("Enter a number (0 to end): ")
    y = input()
    num = int(y)
    if num != 0:
        if num > x:
            x = num
    else:
        done = True
print(str(x))
```

Thank you for any advice with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x = ''
done = False
while not done:
    print("Enter a number (0 to end): ")
    y = input()
    if y != '0':
        x = x + y
    else:
        done = True

print(x.count('7'))
```

Comment: This is beautiful! It does exactly what I want with no baggage. Thank you for your time and the solution to my headache!

Comment: Happy to Help. You may freely contact for any other help

Answer (score 3):

Consider

```
from collections import Counter

nums = []
c = Counter()
done = False
while not done:
    y = int(input("Enter a number (0 to end): "))
    if y == 0:
        done = True
    else:
        c.update([y])
        print(c)
```

Example output:

```
Enter a number (0 to end): 1
Counter({1: 1})
Enter a number (0 to end): 2
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1})
Enter a number (0 to end): 2
Counter({2: 2, 1: 1})
Enter a number (0 to end): 2
Counter({2: 3, 1: 1})
Enter a number (0 to end): 0
```

This will obviously break if user inputs a non-integer. Remove `int(input..)` or add `try-except` if needed.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but a nice bit of code that I will keep in mind for future reference. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: After the braking of the loop if you can use `print(c.get(7,'0'))` ,maybe serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code sample. It expects the first input as the number which you want to search in the list. Followed by list of number each on a separate line.

```
x = 0
done = False
count = 0
i = input("Which number to search: ")
print("Enter list of numbers to search number",i,", enter each on separate line and 0 to end): ")
while not done:
        j = input()
        num = int(j)
        if int(j) == 0 :
                print("exitting")
                break
        else:
                if j == i:
                        count += 1
print("Found number",i,"for",count,"number of times")
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but I will keep it in mind for similar things in the future. Thank you for your time and help!